# Css selector for exact class name

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

I am trying to make a css selector query for exact class name .

Consider this html

```
<div class="My class1">Some long text</div>
<div class="My class1 234">Some long text2</div>
<div class="My class1">Some long text3</div>
<div class="My class1 haha">Some long text2</div>
```

Now i want to catch only class 'My class1' ...and ignore the 'My class1 234' or 'My class1 haha'..

The query $$('div.My class1') , gives me all the 4 above . 
Note : I am trying on firebug console..

How to specify the exact class name here so to get only that particular class ?

Thanks

Comment: Do either of the answers match your requirements? If not, why not? Feedback is important.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

jQuery equals selector: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

```
jQuery("[class='My class1']").
```

or

```
$("[class='My class1']").
```

or

```
$$("[class='My class1']").
```

Comment: Why are you assuming the OP is using jQuery? Especially considering the last line is not jQuery.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know which framework/class is represented by `$$`. jQuery is most common, and it works the same in mootools, see http://mootools.net/docs/core125/core/Utilities/Selectors

Answer (score 7):

### Attribute Selector Syntax

For straight CSS it is:

```
[class='My class1']
```

**For most javascript frameworks like jQuery, MooTools, etc., it is going to be the same selector string used as for the straight CSS.**

The key point is to use an attribute selector to do it, rather than selecting directly by the class name itself. The `class=` (with just the equals sign) will *only* select for an exact match of the string following. If you also have need of catching `class1 My` then you would need to select as well for `[class='class1 My']`. That would cover the two cases where only those two classes are applied (no matter the order in the html).

Answer (score 6):

Class definitions in elements are separated by spaces, as such your first element infact has both classes 'My' and 'class1'.

If you're using Mootools, you can use the following:

```
$$("div.My.class1:not(div.234):not(div.haha)")
```

Example in Mootools: http://jsfiddle.net/vVZt8/2/

Reference: http://mootools.net/docs/core125/core/Utilities/Selectors#Selector:not

If you're using jQuery, you can use the following:

```
$("div.My.class1").not("div.234").not("div.haha");
```

Example in jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/vVZt8/3/

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

These two examples basically retrieve all elements with the classes 'My' and 'class1', and then remove any elements that are a 'div' element which have the either of the '234' or 'haha' classes assigned to them.